# Rails precompile trying to reference tmp file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline, precompile

I'm trying to precompile my assets and Rails keeps throwing an error about missing a `.lock` file in the `tmp` directory:

```
rake aborted!
No such file or directory - /.../My-App/tmp/cache/assets/sprockets%2Ffa8030279a511d669a1c26925f5bb97520130214-20129-dtn8tg.lock
```

The error shows up when I add the line

```
config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

to my `application.rb` file, as per the instructions on Heroku.  I've tried running `rake assets:clean`, which seems to run fine but doesn't solve the problem.

Any idea why it's referencing a `.lock` file in the `tmp` directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After much change, I just decided to close textmate and delete the `tmp` folder.  After that, everything works as expected...

Answer (score 0):

For the tmp and .lock it's by design of the [file_store](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activesupport/lib/active_support/cache/file_store.rb#L103).

As suggested [here](https://github.com/sstephenson/sprockets/issues/136), check the in-memory implementation.

> Can you try `config.assets.cache_store = :memory`. If that works, its
>   a bug with Rails' `FileStore`.

Are you on windows ? Probably the path `/.../` is too long ?

Comment: I'm on a Mac.  Switching to `:memory` did not fix the problem... I also tried using `:dalli_store` with memcachier on Heroku, also no luck...